# Exporting SVG to EPS with 1 pixel = 1 unit

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, eps

I am creating SVG files programmatically and I want to export them in DXF or EPS for a laser cutter and CNC router. Illustrator can export to DXF with settings "1 pixel = 1 unit."

Inkscape has built-in export to EPS with this command

```
inkscape -f input.svg -E output.eps
```

shows on software such as VCarvePro as three times smaller. I found no relevant vector export option in the [help page](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html), only commands relevant to bitmaps and rasterizing.

Answer (score 1):

For an existing document, you need to set this in the document's document settings.

In Inkscape 0.92.3, you need to:

1. Open File > Document properties, first tab ('Page')
2. Set 'Display units' to 'px' (Edit: I think for EPS, you may need to use 'pt' here), copy the number it now says in the 'Scale' field.
3. Set 'Scale' to 1
4. Now resize your drawing's content back to its previous size:
   a) Select all in all layers with Ctrl+Alt+A
   b) Open the transform dialog with Ctrl+Shift+M
   c) In the 'Scale' tab, select % as unit, check the 'Scale proportionally' checkbox, then in either the width or the height field, enter '/' and then paste the copied scale value.
   d) Click Apply.

To avoid doing this for new files, use the px (edit: pt?) template that you can find under File > New from template ... : default px (might be pt).

Sorry for the edits, please test and give feedback if px or pt work.

Comment: Thanks Moini. I tried both solutions with an existing document and a new document. With an existing document, I could not find "display units" and changed General > Defaults units, which had no effect at all, and Page Size > Custom size > Units from px to pt, which changed the width from 900 to 720. I also tried setting it from the template, or with the line `<sodipodi:namedview inkscape:document-units="pt">`. In all cases, the export to EPS had a width of 254 instead of 900. The manual export to DXF worked fine with a width of 900 and I want to do that programmatically.

Comment: Are you using 0.92.3? As far as I know, export to ps/eps via command line does indeed use 90 (before 0.92) / 96 (since 0.92) dpi only. dxf export should be different.

Comment: Due to the pandemic, I didn't get a chance to test this, and now I'm unlikely to do so. But thank you for your help!